# Stopping a TranslateTransform when the checkbox is unchecked

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox, simulation

I have a translation transformation in C# WPF that starts when a checkbox is ticked, and I would like it to stop when you uncheck the checkbox, naturally. How do I do this?

Thx

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that you have an animation contained in a Storyboard that animates properties of the TranslateTransform? In that case you have two methods on the Storyboard: Begin and Stop.

In this case the simplest solution to your problem is to call either Storyboard.Begin or Storyboard.Stop in the Checkbox.Clicked event handler.